# Propel Criteria NOT LIKE with wild card not working for date time column

Tags: php, criteria, propel

I am trying to run following query. But it gives following error. Please advice me if there is any alternative way to do that.

```
$resource_query = AgentsCdr::create()
                        ->withColumn('(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(AgentsCdr.PickupTime)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(AgentsCdr.Calldate))', 'waittime')
                        ->withColumn('(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(AgentsCdr.LastHangup)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(AgentsCdr.Calldate))', 'waittime2')
                        ->filterByCalldate("$sdate $stime",Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL)
                        ->filterByCalldate("$edate $etime",Criteria::LESS_EQUAL)
//here is the issue occurs. Because of 2017-08-09%
                        ->filterByCalldate("2017-08-09%",Criteria::NOT_LIKE);
```

Returning error is `[message:protected] => Error parsing date/time value: '2017-08-09%'`

Can you please suggest me a solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: Take out the %?

Comment: Then search results are wrong. Calldate column date time is storing as Y-m-d H:i:s

Comment: Have you tried it with `where()` instead of `filterByCalldate()`?

Comment: Yes. then also comes same issue.

Comment: Is the Calldate a String?

Comment: No. it is date time.

Comment: To my knowledge wildcards don't work with date time and the same goes for NOT_LIKE, I think. Have you tried it with `->filterByCalldate("2017-08-09 00:00:00",Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL) ->filterByCalldate("2017-08-10 00:00:00",Criteria::LESS);`

Comment: You can also try replacing the first two `->filter()` calls with


`->where('Calldate', "BETWEEN '$sdate $stime' AND '$edate $etime'")`